# SQLite3 AttachDatabase command won't work

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to connect two SQLite databases in a Unity3d project and I am running into some trouble.

My database paths and file names are correct (checked and confirmed), and I am able to query/insert/etc... from each of the databases individually. However, when I run the ATTACH command, it returns an error stating that my SQL logic is invalid. I have looked at many references and examples, all of which indicate that my command should run as anticipated.

Here is some relevant code:

```
//open TEMP database
DBAccess.OpenOrCreateDB("/Resources/Data/SaveGames/" + GameController.user.username +   
    "/", GameController.user.username + "_TEMP");

//attach SAVEGAME database and transfer data from TEMP database
DBAccess.NonQuery("ATTACH DATABASE '" + Application.dataPath + "/Resources/GameData/" 
    + GameController.user.username + "/" + GameController.user.username + DBAccess.DBEXT 
    + "' AS LOAD_DB;");

//copy records from TEMP database to save game database
//(omitted because not relevant to issue)    

//detach SAVEGAME database
DBAccess.NonQuery("PRAGMA LOAD_DB.journal_mode=delete; DETACH DATABASE LOAD_DB;");  

//close database
DBAccess.CloseDB();
```

The goal with this is to copy the in-game changes database to the player's save game database file.

My error debugging prints out the following:

```
DBAccess -- Cannot perform command with statement: <ATTACH '/Users/scottwindsor/ADITL/
Assets/Resources/GameData/New User/New User.db' AS LOAD_DB;>
```

It would seem that my SQL command should work... Any help would be appreciated.

Tech Specs:

- Platform: OSX (Lepoard, I think)
- Compiler: Unity3D (game engine)
- Language: C#
- SQL: SQLite3.dll
- Using IDBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() to send non-query commands to the database.
- Using IDBCommand.ExecuteReader() to send all other commands/queries to the database.

Comment: What' your build target i.e. web, iOS, Android, Standalone?

Comment: Sanity check I'd recommend: does the file exist in the path given?

Comment: Yes. As I previously stated:
"My database paths and file names are correct (checked and confirmed), and I am able to query/insert/etc... from each of the databases individually"